# Matlab - adjust scatter datapoints to centroids 0,0

Tags: matlab

How can I shift/ adjust all the scatter data points so the centroids will be 0,0?

Script:

```
dataFile = dlmread('E:\C.txt'); % file stored in https://ufile.io/km74t
uniqueTable = unique(dataFile,'rows')
dataTable = array2table(uniqueTable,'VariableNames',{'X','Y'})

xCord=dataTable{:,1}
yCord=dataTable{:,2}
scatter(xCord,yCord)

hold on;

centroidX = mean(xCord)
centroidY = mean(yCord)
scatter(centroidX,centroidY)
```

Comment: subtract the centroid from the coordinates? it would be nice if you had provided sample data we could use to reproduce the problem/fix rather than referencing a data file we don't have access to.

Comment: As I recall I can't attached a data file in stackoverflow. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You don't have to attach the whole data file. That would violate the "minimal" part of [mcve]. Providing a few sample data points for `xCord` and `yCord`, however, would be totally appropriate and extremely useful.